# Terminology for equivariant homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, terminology, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy, spanier-whitehead-duality

The usual $G$-equivariant homology and cohomology groups of a space $X$ with $G$-action are given by the Borel construction:
$$H_\ast^G(X)=H_\ast((X\times EG)/G),$$
$$H^\ast_G(X)=H^\ast((X\times EG)/G).$$
Neither of these groups captures the notion of a "homotopically $G$-invariant cycle on $X$".  That notion is instead captured by the group
$$H_{G,\ast}(X)=H_G^\ast(DX)$$
where $D$ denotes Spanier--Whitehead dual.  **Do these groups $H_{G,\ast}$ have a standard name and/or notation?**  They are evidently the place where $G$-equivariant virtual fundamental classes live.

Remark #1: Recall that for any spectrum $X$, there is a canonical isomorphism $H_\ast(X)=H^{-\ast}(DX)$.  The point of the question above is that this isomorphism does not extend to equivariant (co)homology, leading to two different reasonable definitions of $G$-equivariant homology and cohomology.

Remark #2:  It is unfortunate that the standard notation $H^G_\ast$ refers to a group measuring "$G$-co-invariant cycles", while the group I have denoted $H_{G,\ast}$ above measures "$G$-invariant cycles".

Comment: Your $H_{G,-*}(X)$ is called "coBorel homology". (I posted this before with a typo.) For infinite $X$, where you cannot give a definition using duality, this should be understood as the homology of the fixed point spectrum.